# How to get typed value from GenericRecord?

Tags: java, avro

I am working with Avro and I have a `GenericRecord`. I want to extract `clientId`, `deviceName`, `holder` from it. In the Avro Schema, `clientId` is Integer, `deviceName` is String and `holder` is a Map.

`clientId` in the avro schema:

```
{
    "name" : "clientId",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "doc" : "hello"
}
```

`deviceName` in the avro schema:

```
{
    "name" : "deviceName",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "doc" : "test"
}
```

`holder` in the avro schema:

```
{
    "name" : "holder",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : "string"
    }
}
```

My question is - what is the recommended way to retrieve a typed value, as opposed to an Object?

In the below code, `payload` is `GenericRecord` and we can get avro schema from it. This is what I am doing right now, extracting everything as a String. But how can I just get typed value instead. Is there any way? I mean whatever the data type is there in the avro schema, I want to extract that only.

```
  public static void getData(GenericRecord payload) {
    String id = String.valueOf(payload.get("clientId"));
    String name = String.valueOf(payload.get("deviceName"));

    // not sure how to get maps here
  }
```

So I want to extract `clientId` as Integer, `deviceName` as String and `holder` as Java map `Map<String, String>` from `GenericRecord`? What is the best way to do that? Can we write any utility which does all the typed conversions given generic record and schema?

Comment: What type of objects are returned from your three `payload.get` calls?

Comment: @qxz meaning? I didn't understand. It returns everything as an object and then you have to cast it looks like. I guess we can use schema from the payload and write some utility to convert and return back the results.

Comment: For each, try printing `payload.get("...").getClass().getCanonicalName()` to see the type of the object

Comment: ok this is what it prints out `org.apache.avro.util.Utf8` for `deviceName`, 
`java.lang.Integer` for `clientId` and `java.util.HashMap` for `holder`.

Comment: Does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to cast your `string` values to `Utf8`, `int` to `Integer`, and `map` to `Map<Utf8, Utf8>`. This should work without causing a `ClassCastException`:

```
public static void getData(GenericRecord payload) {
    int id = (Integer) payload.get("clientId");
    String name = payload.get("deviceName").toString(); // calls Utf8.toString
    Map<Utf8, Utf8> holder = (Map<Utf8, Utf8>) payload.get("holder");

    ...
}
```

In general, I believe you can do these casts:

- primitives become their boxed version (`Integer`, `Double`, etc.)
- `string` becomes `Utf8`
- `bytes` becomes `java.nio.ByteBuffer`
- `array` becomes `java.util.Collection`
- `map` becomes `java.util.Map<Utf8, [value type]>`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach. For robust implementation you should consider the code [generation using schema compilation.](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing+and+deserializing+with+code+generation)

```
package stackoverflow;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Field;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Type;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
import org.junit.Test;

// Just for demonistration; not robust implementation
public class GenericRecordType {
    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        Schema schema = buildSchema();

        GenericRecord record = new Record(schema);
        record.put("clientId", 12);
        record.put("deviceName", "GlassScanner");
        record.put("holder", new HashMap<>());

        Integer value = IntField.clientId.getValue(record);
        String deviceName = StringField.deviceName.getValue(record);
        Map<String, String> mapString = MapOfStringField.holder.getValue(record);

        assertThat(deviceName, is("GlassScanner"));
        assertThat(value, is(12));
        assertThat(mapString.size(), is(0));
    }

    private Schema buildSchema() {
        Field clientId = new Field("clientId", Schema.create(Type.INT), "hello", (Object) null);
        Field deviceName = new Field("deviceName", Schema.create(Type.STRING), "hello", (Object) null);
        Field holder = new Field("holder", Schema.createMap(Schema.create(Type.STRING)), null, (Object) null);
        Schema schema = Schema.createRecord(Arrays.asList(clientId, deviceName, holder));
        return schema;
    }

    public static interface TypedField<T> {
        String name();

        public T getValue(GenericRecord record);

    }

    public static enum StringField implements TypedField<String> {
        deviceName;

        @Override
        public String getValue(GenericRecord record) {
            String typed = null;
            Object raw = record.get(name());
            if (raw != null) {
                if (!(raw instanceof String || raw instanceof Utf8)) {
                    throw new AvroTypeException("string type was epected for field:" + name());
                }
                typed = raw.toString();
            }
            return typed;
        }

    }

    public static enum IntField implements TypedField<Integer> {
        clientId;

        private IntField() {
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getValue(GenericRecord record) {
            Integer typed = null;
            Object raw = record.get(name());
            if (raw != null) {
                if (!(raw instanceof Integer)) {
                    throw new AvroTypeException("int type was epected for field:" + name());
                }
                typed = (Integer) raw;
            }
            return typed;
        }

    }

    public static enum MapOfStringField implements TypedField<Map<String, String>> {
        holder;

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Map<String, String> getValue(GenericRecord record) {
            Map<String, String> typed = null;
            Object raw = record.get(name());
            if (raw != null) {
                if (!(raw instanceof Map)) {
                    throw new AvroTypeException("map type was epected for field:" + name());
                }
                typed = (Map<String, String>) raw;
            }
            return typed;
        }
    }

}
```